# Quiero hacer un codigo que me permita tener williams fractals de otras temporalidades en la temporalidad actual

Tags: pine-script

```
    //@version=5
    indicator("Williams Fractals", shorttitle="Fractals", format=format.price, precision=0, 
    overlay=true,timeframe = "")
    // Define "n" as the number of periods and keep a minimum value of 2 for error handling.
    n = input.int(title="Periods", defval=2, minval=2)


    // UpFractal
    bool upflagDownFrontier = true
bool upflagUpFrontier0 = true
bool upflagUpFrontier1 = true
bool upflagUpFrontier2 = true
bool upflagUpFrontier3 = true
bool upflagUpFrontier4 = true

for i = 1 to n
    upflagDownFrontier := upflagDownFrontier and (high[n-i] < high[n])
    upflagUpFrontier0 := upflagUpFrontier0 and (high[n+i] < high[n])
    upflagUpFrontier1 := upflagUpFrontier1 and (high[n+1] <= high[n] and high[n+i + 1] < high[n])
    upflagUpFrontier2 := upflagUpFrontier2 and (high[n+1] <= high[n] and high[n+2] <= high[n] and high[n+i + 2] < high[n])
    upflagUpFrontier3 := upflagUpFrontier3 and (high[n+1] <= high[n] and high[n+2] <= high[n] and high[n+3] <= high[n] and high[n+i + 3] < high[n])
    upflagUpFrontier4 := upflagUpFrontier4 and (high[n+1] <= high[n] and high[n+2] <= high[n] and high[n+3] <= high[n] and high[n+4] <= high[n] and high[n+i + 4] < high[n])
flagUpFrontier = upflagUpFrontier0 or upflagUpFrontier1 or upflagUpFrontier2 or upflagUpFrontier3 //or upflagUpFrontier4

upFractal = (upflagDownFrontier and flagUpFrontier)


// downFractal
bool downflagDownFrontier = true
bool downflagUpFrontier0 = true
bool downflagUpFrontier1 = true
bool downflagUpFrontier2 = true
bool downflagUpFrontier3 = true
bool downflagUpFrontier4 = true

for i = 1 to n
    downflagDownFrontier := downflagDownFrontier and (low[n-i] > low[n])
    downflagUpFrontier0 := downflagUpFrontier0 and (low[n+i] > low[n])
    downflagUpFrontier1 := downflagUpFrontier1 and (low[n+1] >= low[n] and low[n+i + 1] > low[n])
    downflagUpFrontier2 := downflagUpFrontier2 and (low[n+1] >= low[n] and low[n+2] >= low[n] and low[n+i + 2] > low[n])
    downflagUpFrontier3 := downflagUpFrontier3 and (low[n+1] >= low[n] and low[n+2] >= low[n] and low[n+3] >= low[n] and low[n+i + 3] > low[n])
    downflagUpFrontier4 := downflagUpFrontier4 and (low[n+1] >= low[n] and low[n+2] >= low[n] and low[n+3] >= low[n] and low[n+4] >= low[n] and low[n+i + 4] > low[n])
flagDownFrontier = downflagUpFrontier0 or downflagUpFrontier1 or downflagUpFrontier2 or downflagUpFrontier3 //or downflagUpFrontier4

downFractal = (downflagDownFrontier and flagDownFrontier)

plotshape(downFractal, style=shape.triangledown, location=location.belowbar, offset=-n, color=#F44336, size = size.tiny)
plotshape(upFractal, style=shape.triangleup,   location=location.abovebar, offset=-n, color=#009688, size = size.tiny)
```

Este es el codigo que viene por default en tradingview del indicador williams Fractals, yo quise cambiar los valores high y low con la funcion security

highT= request.security(syminfo.tickerid, (Ingreso de otra temporalidad) , high, lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)
lowT= request.security(syminfo.tickerid, (Ingreso de otra temporalidad),low, lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)

Yo lo estoy buscando usar para una temporalidad de 5 min, cuando hago el input de la temporalidad de 15, en 5 min si figuran los williams fractals obviamente en otra posicion dado que el true lo entrega 30 min luego de hacer el low que es candidato a ser william Fractal pero solicitando los datos de otra temporalidad de 1 hora en adelante el codigo parece no hacer nada.

Mi intencion es Generar un indicador de williams Fractals que tenga como input la temporalidad y marque el williams fractal del input independientemente de en que temporalidad este